# python3-Write a function mystruct(text) that counts the number of specific character structures within the string text

Tags: python-3.8

Write a function mystruct(text) that counts the number of specific character structures within the string text. The structure consists of the character G followed by
from the character A or T until there is a double GG. For example you can see as text = GAATAGG or text = GAATATTTGG.

def structur(letter,text):
s=0
if letter==G:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you could write this function.
Option 1 is possibly simpler to read, especially for beginners, since it's more explicit while Option 2 is "cleaner."

```py
def count_chars(letter, text) -> int:
    """
    Option 1:
    Add 1 to a variable that keeps track of the number of occurences of
    `letter` and return the final value of the variable.
    """

    count = 0

    for char in text:
        if char == letter:
            count += 1
    
    return count


def count_chars(letter, text) -> int:
    """
    Option 2:
    Append all occurences of `letter` to a list and then return the length
    of the list.
    """

    count = [char for char in text if char == letter]

    return len(count)
```

Please note that both options are case-sensitive so:

- `count_chars("G", "GAATAGG")` will return `3`
- `count_chars("g", "GAATAGG")` will return `0`